# My page got blank in react js when i add .tofixed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
when i run npm my site works perfect but when i add the value {((data.main.temp)-273.15).toFixed . it gets blank.
```

when i remove it my page come live again help me to fix this.
i am creating weather site with react js. the site works fine without that value but when i add that value the page get blanked.  here is my code
when i run npm my site works perfect but when i add the value {((data.main.temp)-273.15).toFixed . it gets blank.
when i remove it my page come live again help me to fix this.
i amc reating weather site with react js. the site works fine without that value but when i add that value the page get blanked.  here is my code

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import  './style.css';
 export function Weather (){

  const apikey = "1815b2003ad4cef38e6b16343a9034ca"
  const [input, setInput] = useState ("")
const [data, setData] = useState({})


const getdetail = (cityName) => {
  const apiURL = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + cityName + "&appid=" + apikey
  axios.get(apiURL).then((res)=>{
    console.log("response",res.data)

setData (res.data)

  }).catch((err)=> {
    console.log("err", err)
  })
}
const handleinput = (e) =>{
  setInput(e.target.value)
}

const handle = () => {
  getdetail(input)
}
useEffect(()=>{
getdetail("delhi")
}, [])
  return(


<>

<div className="col-md-12">
  <div className="weat">
  <div className="container"> 
    <h2 className="hed">Weather</h2></div>
    <img className="img-fluid" src="bc.jpg" alt="" />
    <div><h3>{data.name}</h3></div>
    <div><h2>{((data.main.temp)-273.15).toFixed (2)}°C</h2></div>
    <div className="container in
    ">
      
    <input type="text" value={input} onChange={handleinput}/><br/><br/>
    <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={handle}>button </button>
    </div>
   
    
  
  </div>
 
</div>




</>
  )
}
```

Comment: I think you have added empty space after toFixed function please remove it.

Comment: What's the error message in your javascript console? My best guess is that you need to call the function, i.e. `toFixed()` instead of `toFixed`.

Comment: what is the exact error in the console ?

Answer (score 1):

Either do:

```js
const [data, setData] = useState({main: {temp: 0}})
```

Or:

```
<div><h2>{((data?.main?.temp)-273.15).toFixed(2)}°C</h2></div>
```

You also have space between `.toFixed` and the `()` but that should not be causing issues. Most likely it's because you are trying to read a key out of data, when data is undefined, because the first render happens before the async call for data is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Check type of this exprsession ((data.main.temp)-273.15)

I suppose, that this expression ((data.main.temp)-273.15) can be undefined, because when this page renders first time you have empty object in your state, because function **getdetail** - is async function.